# Adding CartoDB basemap to QGIS

Tags: qgis, carto, basemap

I am trying to add a CartoDB basemap to QGIS and am 1) trying to figure out if it is possible and 2) trying to figure out how to do it.

I've installed the QGIS CartoDB plug-in and have connected to my account. When I select Add CartoDB layer from Web >> CartoDB Plugin >> Add CartoDB Layer I only see the data layers I've uploaded to CartoDB, not any base maps. How can I access the basemaps?

Even after installing QuickMapServices I do not see that CartoDB base map: [image]

Comment: The plugin is only for data from your own account, see https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QgisCartoDB/

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried QuickMapServices plugin? http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/

Settings → More Services → Get contributed pack

Comment: Yes, I have. However, QuickMapServices does not contain the basemaps used by CartoDB

Comment: Hmm and what is it I see) http://m-d.me/img/ss/20160608-x8y-31kb.jpg Go to QMS settings, More services tab

Comment: That's strange. I see something different. I've added a screen shot above.

Comment: Settings → More Services → Get contributed pack

Comment: @MaximDubinin could you add the above comment to your answer so I can mark as complete?

Comment: I'm not Maxim but I've updated my answer.

Comment: too bad for me)