# Using CartodB in Qgis2web?

Tags: carto, qgis2web

Is it possible to add Cartodb map in the Qgis2web plugin in Qgis?

I tried but I couldn't choose CartodB maps like a basemap

Answer (score 2):

First, a caveat: I don't know anything about Carto basemaps and any licences they require, so this info is provided as is. I've not tested qgis2web with Carto basemaps for this reason.

You can add XYZ layers into QGIS by specifying their URL(s) - use the browser panel (https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#the-browser-panel). XYZ layers are then exported by qgis2web.

See also this relevant answer: [Adding CartoDB basemap to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197610/adding-cartodb-basemap-to-qgis?rq=1)